# How to pass Expression<Func<int>> to a function

Tags: c#, .net, linq, lambda

Assume the following programm:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

namespace Lambda {
    class Program {
        public void TheFunction<T> (Expression<Func<T>> action) { 
        /** logic **/
        }

        static void Main (string[] args) {    
            TheFunction(); //this will of course not compile,
                           // because the Lambda Expression is missing. 
        }
    }

    public class foo {
        public int bar { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The Question here is how to call TheFunction? The Goal is to Work with the Expression> in order to retrieve the Property name besides other things, within TheFunction.

I would like to have something like this:

```cs
//...
TheFunction((foo f)=> f.bar);
//...
```

But when i try it will say, that the type arguments cannot be infered from the usage and i should try to specify them, but how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is `(foo f) => f.bar` is not compatible with `Func<T>`. Your lamba function takes one argument of type `foo` and returns an `int`, hence you have to declare `TheFunction` this way:

```
public void TheFunction<TArg, TResult> (Expression<Func<TArg, TResult>> action) { … }
```

then this code will compile fine:

```
new Program().TheFunction((foo b) => b.bar);
```

Side note: `Main` is a static method, hence you need to instantiate `Program` first to be able to call `TheFunction`.

Comment: It would make more sense to use the naming `Func<TArg, TResult>` than the opposite one you have, so I suggest you swap the type parameters to `Func<,>`.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen Yes, you are right, I didn't double-check the docs… Thanks for this.